Pulling bond breadth data from the Finra API is not working – why?
I found the following example on quant-trading, as to how to pull data from Finra API, which worked fine for me, in this particular example
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import pandas as pd
import requests

#EXAMPLE FOR FIXED INCIME
#assign dataset to request
groupName = 'fixedIncomeMarket'
datasetName = 'treasuryWeeklyAggregates'


#build url

url = f'https://api.finra.org/data/group/{groupName}/name/{datasetName}'

#create headers
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }

#create custom filter
customFilter = {
    "limit" : 5000    
        }


#make POST request
request = requests.post(url,headers=headers,json=customFilter)

#format to dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(request.json())

data

But when I try the same thing for the dataset im trying to pull, which has the following parameters, its not working:
groupName = 'fixedIncomeMarket'
datasetName = 'corporate144AMarketBreadth'

I get this error message:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 33
     30 request = requests.post(url,headers=headers,json=customFilter)
     32 #format to dataframe
---> 33 data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(request.json())
     35 data

File ~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:1760, in DataFrame.from_dict(cls, data, orient, dtype, columns)
   1754     raise ValueError(
   1755         f"Expected 'index', 'columns' or 'tight' for orient parameter. "
   1756         f"Got '{orient}' instead"
   1757     )
   1759 if orient != "tight":
-> 1760     return cls(data, index=index, columns=columns, dtype=dtype)
   1761 else:
   1762     realdata = data["data"]

File ~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:709, in DataFrame.__init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    703     mgr = self._init_mgr(
    704         data, axes={"index": index, "columns": columns}, dtype=dtype, copy=copy
    705     )
    707 elif isinstance(data, dict):
    708     # GH#38939 de facto copy defaults to False only in non-dict cases
--> 709     mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
    710 elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    711     from numpy.ma import mrecords

File ~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:481, in dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype, typ, copy)
    477     else:
    478         # dtype check to exclude e.g. range objects, scalars
    479         arrays = [x.copy() if hasattr(x, "dtype") else x for x in arrays]
--> 481 return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)

File ~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:115, in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype, verify_integrity, typ, consolidate)
    112 if verify_integrity:
    113     # figure out the index, if necessary
    114     if index is None:
--> 115         index = _extract_index(arrays)
    116     else:
    117         index = ensure_index(index)

File ~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:645, in _extract_index(data)
    642         raise ValueError("Per-column arrays must each be 1-dimensional")
    644 if not indexes and not raw_lengths:
--> 645     raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
    647 if have_series:
    648     index = union_indexes(indexes)

ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index 

Can somebody help me get the data I want?
This is the API manual: https://developer.finra.org/docs (can be searched for the breadth data im looking for, to get the concrete parameters)

The incoming JSON data is not in a format Pandas can understand. You probably need to look into the data itself and figure out what preprocessing needs to be done until it is passed to DataFrame constructor.

Maybe there is an issue with authorization, if we will try to print request.json()
#make POST request
request = requests.post(url,headers=headers,json=customFilter)
print(request.json())

We will see
{'statusCode': 401, 'statusDescription': 'Failed to authenticate, check your authentication token', 'message': 'Unauthorized', 'requestId': '123', 'resource': '/data/group/{group}/name/{name}'}

You can get free client_id and client_secret from finra and use them like this
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

import pandas as pd
import requests


def get_token(api_key, api_secret):

    bearer_token = requests.post(
        "https://ews.fip.finra.org/fip/rest/ews/oauth2/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials",
        auth=(api_key, api_secret),
    )
    return bearer_token.json()["access_token"]


groupName = "fixedIncomeMarket"
datasetName = "corporate144AMarketBreadth"


client_id = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
client_secret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
token = get_token(client_id, client_secret)

url = f"https://api.finra.org/data/group/{groupName}/name/{datasetName}"

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json", "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}

customFilter = {"limit": 5000}


request = requests.get(url, headers=headers, json=customFilter)

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(request.json())
data

